The SDK 'Aspire.AppHost.Sdk/9.0.0' specified could not be found
After installing Visual Studio Community 2022 to version 17.12.3 and installed the .NET 9.0 Runtime, every time I try to create a new .NET Aspire Starter App project or try to add Aspire to an existing project using the .NET Aspire Orchestration support option, I get the following error message:
The SDK 'Aspire.AppHost.Sdk/9.0.0' specified could not be found.
D:\Project\AspireApp\AspireApp.AppHost\AppHost.csproj

I've validated through the Visual Studio Installer that both the .NET Aspire SDK and .NET SDK are installed

I did have .NET Aspire8 installed previously through the .NET workload but uninstalled it thinking that would solve the issue.
Dotnet Info:
PS C:\Windows\system32> dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           9.0.101
 Commit:            eedb237549
 Workload version:  9.0.100-manifests.4a280210
 MSBuild version:   17.12.12+1cce77968

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.101\

.NET workloads installed:
 [aspire]
   Installation Source: VS 17.12.35527.113
   Manifest Version:    8.2.2/8.0.100
   Manifest Path:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.aspire\8.2.2\WorkloadManifest.json
   Install Type:              Msi

Configured to use loose manifests when installing new manifests.

Host:
  Version:      9.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       9d5a6a9aa4

.NET SDKs installed:
  9.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 9.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 9.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 9.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

The things I've tried so far:

Restarting machine (multiple times)
Validated AppHost project is referencing the correct SDK version
Uninstall Aspire .NET 8 SDK from the .NET workloads
Running Visual Studio repair
Uninstalling .NET 9 Runtime and Aspire SDK and reinstalling using Visual Studio installer
Validating and moving C:\Program Files\dotnet\ path in environment variables so it's above the x86 path.
Completely uninstalled Visual Studio and all .NET runtimes from the machine. Reinstalled the latest version of Visual Studio Community.

Here is the project file for the AppHost project
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <Sdk Name="Aspire.AppHost.Sdk" Version="9.0.0" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsAspireHost>true</IsAspireHost>
    <UserSecretsId>27eb1e38-2d85-47ae-9ba0-d59db5b4e75c</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AspireApp.ApiService\AspireApp.ApiService.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AspireApp.Web\AspireApp.Web.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Aspire.Hosting.AppHost" Version="9.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Anyone have any suggestions or know how to fix this issue?
